# Understanding Guava's TypeToken.isAssignableFrom method

Tags: java, generics, reflection, types, guava

I am using the Guava `TypeToken` class to test if instances of an arbitrary type can be assigned to objects of other type.

In the following code snippet, I am testing if types declared as `List` are assignable from `List<String>`, and viceversa:

```
TypeToken rawListType = new TypeToken<List>(){};
TypeToken parameterizedListType = new TypeToken<List<String>>(){};
System.out.println(rawListType.isAssignableFrom(parameterizedListType)); //true
System.out.println(parameterizedListType.isAssignableFrom(rawListType)); //false
```

Why the second call to `isAssignableFrom` returns `false` ?, given that the code below does compile, so I can assign `List<String>` from `List` (with a warning) ?:

```
List l = null;
List<String> l2 = null;
l = l2; 
l2 = l; //Type Safety Warning
```

My intuition is that Guava is answering if instances of these types are assignable without warnings (?). If that is correct, how could I check for *assignability* in the sense of the compiler allowing me to assign an object to another one (with or without warnings), like it is shown in the second code snippet ?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you said, we know the compiler will allow a generic type to be assigned from a raw type, but that doesn't mean assignability. The compiler is doing an implicit unchecked cast (hence the warning).

Since you really want to check assignability of the corresponding raw types, you could just use [`TypeToken.getRawType`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/reflect/TypeToken.html#getRawType%28%29) and then use [`Class.isAssignableFrom`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29).

**EDIT:** As you pointed out, this methodology would count `List<Integer>` and `List<String>` assignable to and from each other. To avoid that I think you need a more generalized solution:

```
boolean checkRawAssignability(TypeToken<?> assigned, TypeToken<?> from) {

    //if from is a raw type, compare raw types instead
    final Type fromType = from.getType();
    if (fromType instanceof Class<?>) {
        return assigned.getRawType().isAssignableFrom((Class<?>)fromType);
    }

    //otherwise use normal methodology
    return assigned.isAssignableFrom(from);
}
```

Note that this solution does not consider array types.

Comment: hi @Paul. It is not exactly what I am looking for, if I check for raw types assignability, then List<Integer> would be assignable from List<String> and so on, and this is not correct.
I am looking for a way to verify assignability even in cases where the compiler would have to add implicit casts behind the courtains.

Comment: your solution seems correct to me, do you have any idea why TypeToken does not do this ?. At least they should have documented that in the method javadoc I think.

Comment: @Sergio: IMHO what TypeToken implements is the more important concept. What the compiler does is a sort of hack (as is the use of raw type itself). Anyway, it should be documented and I'd suggest to [file an issue](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/issues/entry).